# Can't print ggmap's get_map object on mac

Tags: macos, maps, shapefile, ggmap

I have a simple problem. I'm not able to print objects obtained via the get_map function on my Mac. I'm running the following code taken from another threat on stackoverflow:

```
library(ggmap)
library(mapproj)
map <- get_map(location = 'England', zoom = 7)
print(ggmap(map))
```

While the get_map function produces the intended object, the print function does not do its job. Specifically, I get the following error:

```
Error in layer(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", geom = <environment>,  : 
  unused argument (geom_params = list(raster = c("#B0CEFE", "#B0CEFE",
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. I should note that all packages are up to date, including RStudio, which I am using. Note that this function has worked well half a year ago. Not sure what happened.

Thank you!

Comment: I fixed it myself. I re-installed all packages once more and the error went away.

Comment: Get the same error. I suspect it come from the ggplot2 modification. If ggplot2 is up to date (v >= 2.2.0) and ggmap use and old version, it produces that error. The  solution is to update ggmap.